# Как вывести созданный custom postype с созданной таксономией на экран?

Tags: wordpress

Создал custom post type. В нем создал таксономию. В админке появилось, добавил записей, в админке все в порядке. Вот теперь вопрос....КАК мне увидеть записи, сделанные при помощи custom post type и таксономии, на странице своего сайта?

functions.php:

```
// Registration & Create POST_TYPE
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_cars', 0 );

function register_post_cars() {
$args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Cars', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Cars' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add new car', 'text_domain' ),
          ),
    'description' => '',
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/image.png', __FILE__ ),
    'map_meta_cap' => null,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'author',
        'thumbnail',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
        'page-attributes',
        'post-formats',
    ),
    'register_meta_box_cb' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array('taxcars'),
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'cars',
        'with_front' => false,
        'feeds' => false,
        'pages' => true,
    ),
    'permalink_epmask' => EP_PERMALINK,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'delete_with_user' => null,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'rest_base' => $post_type,
    '_builtin' => false,
    );
register_post_type( 'cars', $args );
}

// Registration & Create TAXONOMY
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxmodels', 0 );

function create_taxmodels() {
$args = array(
    'label' => _x( 'Models', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Models', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Model', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Models' ),
        ),
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'meta_box_cb' => null,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'description' => '',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'taxmodels',
        'with_front' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'ep_mask' => EP_NONE,
    ),

    'sort' => null,
    '_builtin' => false, );

register_taxonomy( 'taxmodels', array('cars'), $args );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же, как и обычные записи, только надо указать post_type и таксономию:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'cars',
    'taxmodels'           => 'модель',
    'showposts'           => -1,
    'order'               => 'DESC',
    'orderby'             => 'date',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Нет записей';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: спасибо, выводит, но только фразу "Нет записей", хотя записи я сделал

Comment: Задайте ваше значение taxmodels (я же не знаю, что там у вас) или уберите taxmodels совсем

Comment: а можете подсказать? Я делаю плагин, который создает постайп и таксономию. Ваш код добавляется в файл page, index или home.php темы и таксономия отображается. А как в плагине мне это реализовать?У меня мысль, что в плагине создается шаблон страницы, а потом в файле плагина эта страница с шаблоном должна как-то подключиться к выбранной теме...ну как-то так...

Comment: Я бы сделал это шорткодом и дал пользователю возможность втыкать шорткод в любое место его сайта.

Comment: отличная идея!!!!спасибо большое!!!!